# remove file from all git history

Tags: node.js, git, git-rewrite-history

Based on this [article](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/), I've created a small script which is supposed to remove all occurrences of a file in the entire git repo, all branches, tags and commits. 
The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var child_process = require('child_process');
if (process.argv.length < 3){
  console.error('USAGE: git-forget path/to/file')
  process.exit(1);
}
var path = process.argv[2];

var phase = 0;
function printLog(error, stdout, stderr) {
  if (error) {
    console.error('ERROR' + error);
  }
  console.log(++phase);
  console.log(stdout);
}

child_process.execSync('git filter-branch --force --index-filter \'git rm -f --cached --ignore-unmatch  '+ path +'\' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all');
child_process.execSync('echo "' + path + '" >> .gitignore', printLog);
child_process.execSync('git add .gitignore');
child_process.execSync('git commit -m "Add ' + path +' to .gitignore"',printLog)
child_process.execSync('git push origin --force --all',printLog);
child_process.execSync('git push origin --force --tags',printLog);
```

This script worked on a few repos (which are private) and on a specific one it kept the initial commit to the file I was trying to remove. After the script was run I did this `git log --all -- .npmrc` and found the initial commit. What am I missing?

Comment: sidenote: checkout [BFG, a simpler, faster alternative to git-filter-branch](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner)

Comment: tried bfg, it works locally but doesn't update remote

Comment: @qballer, then force push your changes to the remote?

Comment: @chris nope, it says everything is up to date. I think it has to do with the fact the critical file was introduced in the initial commit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what happened is that you forgot to tell other users of this repo not to *merge* their changes to the new history, but rather to *rebase*.
From the document you quoted:

> Tell your collaborators to rebase, not merge, any branches they
>   created off of your old (tainted) repository history. One merge commit
>   could reintroduce some or all of the tainted history that you just
>   went to the trouble of purging.

Try running the same script again, and see that no one re-introduces the old history by means of merging his/her local changes to the new head.

Comment: while it seems you are right, I have no idea on how to resolve this.